# How to handle iregulare closed client connections

Tags: netty

I have tested a simple server using netty 4.0.23.Final. It is the official example telnet server:

http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/telnet/package-summary.html

My problem is now, when I access the server and kill the client iregulary by killing the pid I get following error thrown:

```
java.io.IOException: Connection closed by remote client
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    ...
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    ...
```

The reason is clear, the connection was closed irgulary. I can also handle this state by having:

```
@see io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter#channelUnregistered(io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext)

@Override
public void channelUnregistered(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    final String host = ((InetSocketAddress) ctx.channel().remoteAddress()).getAddress().getHostAddress();
    final int port = ((InetSocketAddress) ctx.channel().remoteAddress()).getPort();
    System.out.println(String.format("unregistered host:%s port:%d", host, port));
    super.channelUnregistered(ctx);
}
```

But: how can I get rid /capture the error message? I would like to capture it that way that it is not shown in my log. How do I have to change the netty example ?

Thank you very much, any help is welcome.

The full example: http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/telnet/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the problem. Catching this exception is already implemented. Just uncomment the print stack trace:

```
@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
  // cause.printStackTrace();
  ctx.close();
}
```

Comment: true, you can delete this method too.